# The program I created can be seen but pressing the button doesn't do anything. What is wrong with the code one of it's controls?

Tags: vb.net

I know that in the code below I tried to get the part of the code that is there so that text will be displayed when the program runs to work in three different ways (the to string method, leaving the variable as integers and just words (I wrote it before I made the variables and before I knew that I had to create variables). I did this because I was just trying to the program  to display anything so that I knew I was on the right track but I didn't think that all three ways were the right way.

The program I am creating is a program that will let you know if a certain year is a leap year. The user is supposed to enter a number between 1 to 12 for the month and whichever year they would like to enter and the program is supposed to let the user know if the year they typed in is a leap year. (Technically EVERY 4 years is not a leap year.)

When I press the button that is suppose to make this happen nothing happens. The code is below. What is wrong with it. (I purposely left about half of the select case part because I wasn't sure if I was doing it right or not.)

```
    Dim intNumber As Integer
    intNumber = 0
    Dim strMonth As String
    strMonth = String.Empty
    Dim intMonth As Integer
    intMonth = 0
    Dim intYear As Integer
    intYear = 0
    Dim strYear As String
    strYear = String.Empty
    Dim strDays As String
    strDays = String.Empty
    intMonth = CInt(txtEnterMonth.Text)
    intYear = CInt(txtEnterYear.Text)
    Dim intDays As Integer
    intDays = 0
    Dim blnLeapYear As Boolean
    blnLeapYear = False
    strDays = intDays.ToString
    strMonth = intMonth.ToString
    strYear = intYear.ToString
    If Integer.TryParse(txtEnterMonth.Text, intMonth) Then
        If intNumber > 1 And intNumber <= 12 Then
            If Integer.TryParse(txtEnterMonth.Text, intYear) Then
                If intYear >= 1582 Then
                    Select Case CInt(txtEnterMonth.Text)
                        Case 1
                            strMonth = "Jan"
                            intDays = 31
                            strDays = intDays.ToString
                        Case 2
                            strMonth = intMonth.ToString
                            strYear = intYear.ToString
                            If intYear Mod 4 = 0 Then
                                If intYear Mod 100 = 0 AndAlso intYear Mod 400 <> 0 Then
                                    blnLeapYear = False
                                    If blnLeapYear = True Then
                                        intDays = 29
                                    Else
                                        intDays = 28
                                    End If
                                End If
                                If blnLeapYear = True Then
                                    intDays = 29
                                    intDays = 28
                                Else
                                End If
                            End If
                        Case 3
                            strMonth = "Mar"
                            intDays = 31
                            strDays = intDays.ToString
                    End Select
                    strDays = intDays.ToString
                    strMonth = intMonth.ToString
                    strYear = intYear.ToString
                    If intYear < Today.Year Then
                        If blnLeapYear Then
                            lblDisplayResult.Text = strMonth & strYear & "had " & strDays & "days " & strYear & "was a a leap year."
                        Else
                            lblDisplayResult.Text = strMonth & strYear & "had" & intDays.ToString & "days"
                        End If
                    Else
                        If blnLeapYear Then
                            lblDisplayResult.Text = "Month " & "year " & "will have " & "days " & "days." & "Year " & "Will be a leap year"
                        Else
                            lblDisplayResult.Text = "Month " & "Year" & "will have" & "days" & "days"
                        End If
                    End If
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Enter 1582 or later")
                End If
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Enter a number 1 to 12.")
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: Where is this code?  Is it inside a method that handles the button's Press event?

Comment: You are using `txtEnterMonth.Text` for both the intMonth and the intYear.